# Wierd behavior on channel creation with kafka ordering service on hyperledger fabric

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, channel

So I was creating a channel using the cli container with the command `peer channel create -f config/allarewelcome.tx -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c allarewelcome` and I get these messages. The channel ends up being created as you can see but I wonder what is happening. Does anyone have an idea?

> UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
>
> UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 004 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
>
> UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 005 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 006 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
>
> UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 007 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 008 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
>
> UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 009 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 00a Received block: 0

Here are my kafka clusters and zookeepers definitions on my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
  kafka0.example.com:
    container_name: kafka0.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.example.com:2181,zookeeper1.example.com:2181,zookeeper2.example.com:2181
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    networks:
      - basic
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - zookeeper3.example.com

  kafka1.example.com:
    container_name: kafka1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.example.com:2181,zookeeper1.example.com:2181,zookeeper2.example.com:2181
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
    ports:
      - 10092:9092
      - 10093:9093
    networks:
      - basic
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - zookeeper3.example.com

  zookeeper1.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper0.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment: 
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper1.example.com:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper2.example.com:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper3.example.com:2888:3888
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    networks:
      - basic

  zookeeper2.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment: 
      - ZOO_MY_ID=2
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper1.example.com:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper2.example.com:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper3.example.com:2888:3888
    ports:
      - 12181:2181
      - 12888:2888
      - 13888:3888
    networks:
      - basic

  zookeeper3.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment: 
      - ZOO_MY_ID=3
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper1.example.com:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper2.example.com:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper3.example.com:2888:3888
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
      - 22888:2888
      - 23888:3888
    networks:
      - basic
```

And here is my logs from the orderer:

> UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 014 Getting block information from block storage
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 015 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59044 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=107.803049ms
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] newChain -> INFO 016 [channel: allarewelcome] Starting chain with last persisted offset -3 and last recorded block [0]
>
> UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 017 Created and starting new chain allarewelcome
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] setupTopicForChannel -> INFO 018 [channel: allarewelcome] Setting up the topic for this channel...
>
> UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 019 [channel: allarewelcome] Rejecting deliver request for 192.168.0.18:59042 because of consenter error
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 01a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59042 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=112.653714ms
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] setupProducerForChannel -> INFO 01b [channel: allarewelcome] Setting up the producer for this channel...
>   2020-01-08 14:56:58.253 UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] startThread -> INFO 01c [channel: allarewelcome] Producer set up successfully
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] sendConnectMessage -> INFO 01d [channel: allarewelcome] About to post the CONNECT message...
>
> UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 01e [channel: allarewelcome] Rejecting deliver request for 192.168.0.18:59046 because of consenter error
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 01f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59046 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=186.949863ms
>
> UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 020 [channel: allarewelcome] Rejecting deliver request for 192.168.0.18:59052 because of consenter error
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 021 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59052 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=201.05081ms
>
> UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 022 [channel: allarewelcome] Rejecting deliver request for 192.168.0.18:59054 because of consenter error
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 023 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59054 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=201.212849ms
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] startThread -> INFO 024 [channel: allarewelcome] CONNECT message posted successfully
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] setupParentConsumerForChannel -> INFO 025 [channel: allarewelcome] Setting up the parent consumer for this channel...
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] startThread -> INFO 026 [channel: allarewelcome] Parent consumer set up successfully
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] setupChannelConsumerForChannel -> INFO 027 [channel: allarewelcome] Setting up the channel consumer for this channel (start offset: -2)...
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] startThread -> INFO 028 [channel: allarewelcome] Channel consumer set up successfully
>
> UTC [orderer.consensus.kafka] startThread -> INFO 029 [channel: allarewelcome] Start phase completed successfully
>
> UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.18:59056 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=203.740188ms

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Should I be receiving these messages `UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}`?

Comment: Those are INFO messages. What's the problem with them? It's not clear what "service" is unavailable

Comment: I'll re-build the containers with debug logging level to see more info. The problem (at least in my opinion) is that the ordering service should be available at all time right?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if the channel is created yet.
In this case try with:

```
./byfn.sh -m restart -c channelName
```

if you are using byfn, otherwise just restart the network clearning the data.

Also, be sure that when you create the network and you create the channel, you are passing channel name to the peer channel create.

Anyways, this could be also an error related to Kafka.
I personally got this message too when creating the network, even if I am not using Kafka, but I remember I read something about this issue related to a kafka environment variable missing.
Consider that they are warning so you can proceed, your channel seems to be created anyways.

Comment: Please, if this solved, check this as "Answer". thanks